# Auto-Indentation On Close Block in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-indent

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2008 Professional, and it is not auto-indenting blocks of code when the block is closed `}`.  This was a feature I found very useful with Express.  How do I turn it back on?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's.

> Tools->Options->Text
>   Editor->C#->Formatting-> Check
>   Automatically format completed block
>   on }

Comment: Weird. Try to reset your settings: Tools->Import/Export->Reset

Answer (score 2):

Tools->Options->text editor->c#->formatting->select auto format on }

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Tabs->Indenting needs to be set to Smart, in addition to the "Automatically format completed block on }" setting already mentioned.